# Delete a row based on the value of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

right now i have just a list of part numbers listed in column a and parts are added to it or deleted from it during one of the macros i use regularly.

This is the sub i am using right now to delete part numbers:

```
Sub DeleteIfVal(rng As Range, val)
    Dim c As Range, del As Range
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c.Value = val Then
            If del Is Nothing Then
                Set del = c
            Else
                Set del = Application.Union(del, c)
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    If Not del Is Nothing Then del.Delete
End Sub
```

Now I want the list to contain other information about the part (part name, location, etc.), but the sub i have right now only deletes cells rather than entire rows based on just the cell in the first column

Comment: just replace del.Delete with del.EntireRow.Delete

Comment: @IAmDranged Thank you! This works perfectly! If you want to make an answer out of that I will mark it as the right answer for anyone else who views this question.

Answer (score 0):

Get the row itself (instead of its values) by "Range.EntireRow", then delet it.

In other words, instead of "del.Delete", use:

```
del.EntireRow.Delete
```